# Getting the ID's of resources created using a loop in bicep

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I have got a module that creates managed identities within bicep, I designed it as a module which accepts an array as parameter so that I can pass an array of managed identities that I want created and it can be created at once, the issue here is that I need the ID's of the created user managed identity, I was wondering how I can retrieve the ID's and use it elsewhere.

one thing that springs to mind is declaring an array to store the ID's but that doesnt appear to work when I tested it, I am doing this incorrectly.

```
param managedIdentities array
param location string
param tagging object
param managed_identity_properties object

 
  resource create_managed_identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = [ for name in managedIdentities: {
    name: name
    location: location
    tags: tagging.tags
  } ]
  
  // output managedIdentityIds array = [for identity in managedIdentities: identity.id]
  output managedIdentityIds array = [resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', name) for name in managedIdentities]
```

How can I reference the value of the ID in other modules ? Ideally I would like to reference it by providing the managed instance, the array that I am sending to the module looks like this

```
        "mi_resources": [
            "mi-01",
            "mi-02",
            "mi-03",
            "mi-04"
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Getting the ID's of resources created using a loop in bicep:

*Use below code to achieve your requirement.*

```bash
param  managedIdentities  array
param  location  string = resourceGroup().location
resource  create_managed_identity  'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = [ for  name  in  managedIdentities: {
  name: name
  location: location
} ]
output  managedIdentityIds  array = [for  i  in  range(0,  length(managedIdentities)) : create_managed_identity[i].id]
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant; how can I can access the values or pass the value onto another module ?

Comment: You can simply pass it as a parameter from the module as 

`managedIdentityIds: managedIdentityIds`. @learner

Comment: I think that would be passing an entire array, If i only require the ID for `mi-01` for example ?

Comment: You can retrieve it with the index. @learner

Answer (score 0):

**How can I reference the value of the ID in other modules ?**  Regarding this issue, many people will fall into a dilemma, may be encountered in following issue:

> which requires a value that can be calculated at the start of the deployment. Properties of `xxx` which can be calculated at the start include "name"

Module resource reference is tricky in bicep template, [learn more from this](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/7328),
Merely refer the output from module will result in an error as above.

Using **modules** + **existing** keyword to refer id or properties.
below is a sample code:

`managedIdentity.bicep`

```
param location string

param managedIdentities array = [
]

resource create_managed_identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = [ for name in managedIdentities: {
  name: name
  location: location
} ]
```

`main.bicep`

```
param location string = 'eastus'

param managedIdentities array = [
  'wbidentity11'
  'wbidentity22'
]

param containerGroupNames array = [
  'wbcontainer11'
  'wbcontainer22'
]

module idModules 'managedIdentity.bicep' = {
  name: 'idDeploy'
  params: {
    location: location
    managedIdentities: managedIdentities
  }
}

resource identityIds 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' existing = [ for item in managedIdentities: {
  name: item
}]

resource containerGroup 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups@2021-09-01' = [for (name, i) in containerGroupNames: {
  name: name
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${identityIds[i].id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    containers: [
      {
        name: name
        properties: {
          image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld'
          ports: [
            {
              port: 80
              protocol: 'TCP'
            }
          ]
          resources: {
            requests: {
              cpu: 1
              memoryInGB: 2
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    osType: 'Linux'
    restartPolicy: 'Always'
    ipAddress: {
      type: 'Public'
      ports: [
        {
          port: 80
          protocol: 'TCP'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    idModules
  ]
}]
```

---

or you can do it in a simple way to avoid using module.

`singleFileResources.bicep`

```
param location string = 'eastus'

param managedIdentities array = [
  'wbidentity1'
  'wbidentity2'
]
param containerGroupNames array = [
  'wbcontainer1'
  'wbcontainer2'
]

resource create_managed_identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = [ for name in managedIdentities: {
  name: name
  location: location
} ]

resource containerGroup 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups@2021-09-01' = [for (name, i) in containerGroupNames: {
  name: name
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${create_managed_identity[i].id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    containers: [
      {
        name: name
        properties: {
          image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld'
          ports: [
            {
              port: 80
              protocol: 'TCP'
            }
          ]
          resources: {
            requests: {
              cpu: 1
              memoryInGB: 2
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    osType: 'Linux'
    restartPolicy: 'Always'
    ipAddress: {
      type: 'Public'
      ports: [
        {
          port: 80
          protocol: 'TCP'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}]
```